# Changing class of childrens

Tags: jquery, class, children

I have 2d array "active[][]" whan I have 0s and 1s. First look at my html:

```
<div class="place"> 
<div class="bigbaractive">1</div>
    <div class="smallbar"><div class="lock2"></div>1.1</div>
    <div class="smallbar"><div class="lock2"></div>1.2</div>
    <div class="smallbar"><div class="lock2"></div>1.3</div>
    <div class="smallbar"><div class="lock2"></div>1.4</div>
    <div class="smallbar"><div class="lock2"></div>1.5</div>
    <div class="smallbar"><div class="lock2"></div>1.6</div>
    <div class="smallbar"><div class="lock2"></div>1.7</div>
    <div class="smallbar"><div class="lock2"></div>1.8</div>
    <div class="smallbar"><div class="lock2"></div>1.9</div>
</div>

<div class="place">
<div class="bigbaractive">2</div>
        <div class="smallbar"><div class="lock2"></div>2.1</div>
    <div class="smallbar"><div class="lock2"></div>2.2</div>
    <div class="smallbar"><div class="lock2"></div>2.3</div>
    <div class="smallbar"><div class="lock2"></div>2.4</div>
</div>

<div class="place">
<div class="bigbaractive">3</div>
    <div class="smallbar"><div class="lock2"></div>3.1</div>
    <div class="smallbar"><div class="lock2"></div>3.2</div>
    <div class="smallbar"><div class="lock2"></div>3.3</div>
    <div class="smallbar"><div class="lock2"></div>3.4</div>
    <div class="smallbar"><div class="lock2"></div>3.5</div>
    <div class="smallbar"><div class="lock2"></div>3.6</div>
    <div class="smallbar"><div class="lock2"></div>3.7</div>
</div>
```

What I want is change class of smallbars when is 1 at array active. Just look:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    var ile;
    var smallbars = [];
    for(var i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        smallbars = $('.place')[i].find('.smallbar');
        alert(i);
        for(var j=0; j<smallbars.length; j++)
        {
            if(active[i][j] == 1)
            {
                smallbars[j].toggleClass("smallbaractive");
                smallbars[j].firstChild.remove();
            }
        }
    }

});
```

Alert(i) not work after "smallbars = $('.place')[i].find('.smallbar');" but works before. See you any mistakes in my JS code? Please help. I know I can't describe you what I want so just tell me where you see any mistakes. Greatings, I am waiting for responses.

Comment: Little bit difficult to understand what you want. Are you creating html through array? In your example which div should have active class? all smallbar which have "1"? How your 2d array looks like?

Comment: So my 2d array is filled by "0" and "1":
active[which div called "place"][which div inside this "place" div called "smallbar"]=1 or 0; When 1 (look at if(active[i][j] == 1)) remove first child of this smallbar andchange class of this smallbar to smallbaractive. Now it is clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using array syntax on a jQuery object will return a DOM element that is no long wrapped in jQuery. One solution is to use [`.eq(index)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead:

```
 $('.place')[i]     // --> DOM element
 $('.place').eq(i)  // --> jQuery object with just that element
```

However, after looking at your code I would suggest writing it using [`.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to make looping easier on yourself:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var ile;
    var smallbars = [];
    $('.place').each(function(indexPlace, elPlace) {
          $(this).find(".smallbar").each(function(indexSmallBar, elSmallBar) {
            if (active[indexPlace][indexSmallBar] == 1) {
                  $(this).toggleClass("smallbaractive")
                         .find(">:first-child")
                         .remove();
            }
        })
    })
});
```

**[Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pb8hyLm1/1/)**

If you want to get your code working with minimal changes, you could simply use `.eq` in two places where you are using array accessors.

[**Example Fiddle With Minimal Changes**](https://jsfiddle.net/pb8hyLm1/3/)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var active = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]];
    var i = 0;
    $('.place').each(function(){
        var j = 0;
        $(this).children('.smallbar').each(function(){
            if(active[i][j] == 1) {
                $(this).toggleClass('smallbaractive');
                $(this).children(':first').remove();
            }
            j++;
        });
        i++;
    });
});
```

Comment: Would you add into this answer what you changed, or what technique you used to solve the OP's issue? Future readers may find that useful or educational.